# Oracle SQL Developer UPDATE error: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to UPDATE one column using another column in another table? SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050743/how-to-update-one-column-using-another-column-in-another-table-sql-error-ora-0)

I have tried everything I can think of but couldn't solve this SQL error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

This is Oracle SQL.

Have to say, Oracle SQL seems a lot more awkward and hard to use than the open-source version MySQL.... 
Many thanks.

```
UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A 
SET A.POG_ID=B.POG_ID 
FROM POG_HIERARCHY B
WHERE A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY
;
```

Comment: Why do you post the exact same question twice immediately one after the other?. That won't get you faster or better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support `UPDATE FROM` syntax - or didn't last time I looked.

Here is the `BNF`:

```
UPDATE [schema .] { table | view} [ alias ] SET column = { expr | subquery }  [, column = { expr | subquery }]...[WHERE condition] ;
```

(from: http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqcmd.htm)

If you want to set all values of `A.POG_ID`, you can use this syntax:

```
UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A 
SET A.POG_ID=(SELECT B.POG_ID 
          FROM POG_HIERARCHY B 
          WHERE A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY);
```

Or PL/SQL, just to update the rows in `sales_data_family_2007` which are applicable:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
FOR sdf_row_to_update IN (
      SELECT A.ROW_ID sdf_rowid, B.POG_ID 
      FROM POG_HIERACHY B, SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A
      WHERE B.FAMILY=A.FAMILY_ID) LOOP
   UPDATE sales_data_family_2007 
   SET pog_id=sdf_row_to_update.pog_id 
   WHERE rowid=sdf_row_to_update.sdf_rowid;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update rows from a subquery with more than one record you can use the merge commenad:

```
merge into SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A
using (select POG_ID , FAMILY
                 FROM POG_HIERARCHY ) B
on (A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY)
when matched then
update set A.POG_ID=B.POG_ID
```