# How to UPDATE one column using another column in another table? SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01427

I have tried everything I can think of but couldn't solve this SQL error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

This is Oracle SQL.

```
    UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A 
    SET A.POG_ID=B.POG_ID 
    FROM POG_HIERARCHY B 
    WHERE A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY ;
```

One alternative I have tried is as below. Unfortunately it gives another error:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
    UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 
    SET POG_ID= (SELECT POG_HIERARCHY.POG_ID FROM POG_HIERARCHY 
    WHERE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007.FAMILY_ID=POG_HIERARCHY.FAMILY_ID) 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT POG_HIERARCHY.POG_ID FROM POG_HIERARCHY 
    WHERE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007.FAMILY_ID=POG_HIERARCHY.FAMILY_ID) 
    ;
```

Please help!

Comment: The "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" error-message implies that there are multiple `pog_hierarchy` records with the same `family_id`. You need to tell Oracle *which* `pog_hierarchy` record is the *one* whose `pog_id` you want.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to update rows from a subquery with more than one record you can use the merge commenad:

```
merge into SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A
using (select POG_ID , FAMILY
                 FROM POG_HIERARCHY ) B
on (A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY)
when matched then
update set A.POG_ID=B.POG_ID
```

Comment: many thanks. This gives me error: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "B"."FAMILY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier". Now I start wonder if I should use "insert into" instead, but I only want to update ONE column...

Comment: sorry forgot the FAMILY in the "using" inner select, try it now

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A
SET A.POG_ID =
(   
  SELECT P.POG_ID 
  FROM POG_HIERARCHY P
  WHERE A.FAMILY_ID = P.FAMILY_ID 
)
```

Comment: How is that different from what the OP already tried? If the OP's statement returned "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row", then so will yours. No?

Comment: Right, this gives the error:ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: If that's the case you need to figure out what exactly you are trying to do. There are more than one POG_ID in POG_HEIRARCHY for a given FAMILY_ID so you have to decide which POG_ID to use and change the inner query accordingly so that only one row is returned. For example, if you want to use the largest POG_ID, change the inner query to SELECT MAX(P.POG_ID) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A 
SET A.POG_ID= (select B.POG_ID 
                 FROM POG_HIERARCHY B  
                WHERE A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY) ;
```

This will work if and only if there's at most one corresponding row in POD_HIERARCHY for a given FAMILY.  If there's more than one row in POD_HIERARCHY, then you need to determine which row from POD_HIERARCHY you wish to use the value from.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SALES_DATA_FAMILY_2007 A 
SET A.POG_ID= (select B.POG_ID 
                 FROM POG_HIERARCHY B  
                WHERE A.FAMILY_ID=B.FAMILY)
WHERE A.POG_ID IN (SELECT C.POG_ID FROM POG_HIERARCHY C
                   WHERE A.FAMILY_ID = C.FAMILY);
```